# How to resolve Github Nuget Packages Error 500?

Tags: github, github-package-registry

I have packages in my private GitHub account as well as in that of my organisation, which I have always used. Now I wanted to add new to them, so I created a new PAT and tried it out a bit. But now I have the problem that my packages can no longer be accessed. I can access the link:
https://nuget.pkg.github.com/%5BNAME%5D/index.json

but when I try to add this in Visual Studio I get the error message: “Failed to retrieve metadata from source ‘https://nuget.pkg.github.com/%5BNAME%5D/query?q=&skip=0&take=26&prerelease=false&supportedFramework=.NETFramework,Version=v4.8&semVerLevel=2.0.0%E2%80%99.
Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).” When I call the link I get the text: {“error”: “The GitHub Packages service encountered an error.”} . Can anyone help me?

PAT has the rights to all repos, as well as write and delete packages.

I have tried deleting all the packages and uploading them again, I have created a PAT with all the permissions and tried this from different PCs on different networks.

Comment: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error) seems to indicate there is an issue in githubs code. You'll probably just have to wait for them to fix it. Or contact them

Comment: Is this issue resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created a Ticket https://support.github.com/
It seems to be a bug with GitHub itself. They've been working on it for almost a month now.